# Discord bot command from one bot to another

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

Hello guys I have simple discord bot on server and have a music bot. My simple bot just open txt file with links on music and send command in chat m!play link. But music bot doesn't see commands which are sent by my bot.
Music bot Jockie music

import discord
from random import randint
from conf import TOKEN

class DSClient(discord.Client):

```
async def on_ready(self):
    print(self.guilds)

async def on_message(self, message):

    if message.content == "Грязюка":

        with open("songs.txt", "rt") as f:

            tracks = [song.strip().split() for song in f.readlines()]
            for _ in range(len(tracks)):
                index = randint(0, len(tracks) - 1)
                track = tracks.pop(index)
                print(track)
                await message.channel.send(f"m!play {track[0]}")
```

client = DSClient(intents=discord.Intents.default().all())

client.run(TOKEN)

my code

Comment: is your music bot self coded or and self hosted or is it an public bot you just added?

Answer (score -1):

if the bot you want to give commands is not from you you can't fix this ... because they set it in their code so that is will only respond to user accounts.

If the Bot you want to give the command (music bot) is from you, you need to go to the code and make the command triggered by an on_message event, because the build in command handler from discord.py will only listen to user messages and ignore commands send by other bots

```py
@bot.listen
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('m!play'):
        await play_song(song_name=message.content.split(' ')[1])
```

the play_song function is here the async function that will play the song and I just passed here an example parameter.